# D3 y-axis labels don't automatically resize

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, padding, axis

Is there any way in D3 to adjust the axis labels to make sure they show on the screen? [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidbates/0axktnkg/1/)

I can increase the left-padding to allow the y-axis labels to display completely, however is there a way I can do this in a data-driven way?

```
// Calculate dimensions.
var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 250;
var padding = {
    left: 150,
    top: 75,
    bottom: 20,
    right: 100
};
var contentWidth = svgWidth - padding.left - padding.right;
var contentHeight = svgHeight - padding.top - padding.bottom;

...

// Y-Axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");
svg.append("g")
        .classed("yAxis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + ", " + padding.top + ")")
        .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: You could either [wrap them](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) or [determine the bounding box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577430/how-to-properly-get-text-width-to-center-labels-above-graph-bars) after they have been drawn and then set the left padding accordingly. This will require a redraw step though.

Comment: Do you have an example you can point me to where someone does that?

Comment: Both of those links have code samples. You probably want the first option, which comes complete with a function that you can reuse.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see those. Sweet, thanks :)